# Calculate squared deviation from the mean for each element in array

Tags: python, arrays, variance

I have an array with shape `(128,116,116,1)`, where 1st dimension asthe number of subjects, with the 2nd and 3rd being the data.

I was trying to calculate the variance (squared deviation from the mean) at each position (i.e: in (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), etc... until (116,116)) for all the 128 subjects, resulting in an array with shape `(116,116)`.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, someone can help you, when you explain what exactly the problem was that you have encountered. See: [ask]

Comment: You are showing a one-dimensional tuple, but you are talking about 1st, 2nd, and 3rd dimensions in an array. This makes the question really hard to understand. Is `x` the *shape* of your array? It's also not clear how you are using the word `variance` when applying it to a single data point. Do you just mean distance from the mean for that one number?

Comment: I'm afraid this makes no sense at all

Comment: Yes @Mark , x is the shape of my array and the variance is the squared deviation from the mean, sorry about that...

Comment: You were trying to calculate the var ... and how far did you reach? Please mention whether you are getting an error or are just asking how to code such a problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pu239! I have no clue on how to do this...

Comment: Okay! Since you have 2-dimensional data (for any subject), by `variance` do you mean the L2 norm? Or is `variance` defined differently in your question?

Comment: @pu239 the variance I mention is the squared deviation of a variable from its mean, which in python is accomplished by using statistical.variance (as shown here https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a multidimensional list `a` of shape `(3,2,2)`

```
import numpy as np
a =
[
    [
        [1,1],
        [1,1]
    ],
    [
        [2,2],
        [2,2]
    ],
    [
        [3,3],
        [3,3]
    ],
]

np.var(a, axis = 0) # results in:
> array([[0.66666667, 0.66666667],
>        [0.66666667, 0.66666667]])
```

If you want to efficiently compute the variance **across** all 128 subjects (which would be axis `0`), I don't see a way to do it using the `statistics` package since it doesn't take multi-lists as input. So you will have to write your own code/logic and add loops on the subjects. 
But, using the  [`numpy.var`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy-var)
function, we can easily calculate the variance of each 'datapoint' (tuples of indices) across all 128 subjects.

---

**Side note:** You mentioned `statistics.variance`. However, that is only to be used when you are taking a sample from a population as is mentioned in the documentation you linked. If you were to go the manual route, you would use `statistics.pvariance` instead, since we are calculating it on the whole dataset.
The difference can be seen here:

```
statistics.pvariance([1,2,3])
> 0.6666666666666666 # (correct)
statistics.variance([1,2,3])
> 1 # (incorrect)
np.var([1,2,3])
> 0.6666666666666666 # (np.var also gives the correct output)
```

Comment: I though I had to loop through all the lines and rows but it was a lot easier...
Thank you so much @pu239 !!